# Let $G$ be a non-trivial group with no non-trivial proper subgroup. Prove that $G$ cannot be infinite group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be a non-trivial group with no non-trivial proper subgroup. Prove that $G$ cannot be infinite group.

A hints is given as order of G is not infinite since $a$ and $a^{-1}$ are only generators. I know that infinite cyclic group has only two generators. But don't know how to prove the problem.

Comment: What about simplifying the double negation by just asking "Prove that any infinite group contains a nontrivial proper subgroup"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $1 \neq g \in G$. Then $\langle g \rangle \subseteq G$ is a subgroup. Since it is not the trivial subgroup and there are no proper subgroups it is equal to $G$. Thus $G$ is cyclic. Assume $G$ is infinite. Then the group $\langle g^2 \rangle$ is a proper subgroup.

Comment: I understand. Very good reply. I am unable to understand the last line "Then the group $\langle g^2 \rangle$ is a proper subgroup." Also what next

Comment: Well, $\langle g^2 \rangle$ is by definition a subgroup. Since $\operatorname{ord}(g) = \infty$ by assumption, $g^2 \neq 1$ and thus it is not the trivial group. Furthermore we have $g \notin \langle g^2 \rangle$, since otherwise we had $g = g^{2k}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and thus $1 = g^{2k - 1}$ and therefore $g$ had finite order. This yields that $\langle g^2 \rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ which contradicts the assumption that $G$ does not have proper subgroups.

Comment: @menag Would you please elaborate "$⟨g^2⟩ $ is by definition a subgroup". Would you please give me a outline to prove this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Let $G$ be an infinite group, and $g \in G$ a non trivial element.

- What happens if $g$ has finite order?
- If $g$ has infinite order, then consider $\langle g^2\rangle$

Comment: Please write some more lines about $<g^2>$.

Comment: @rama_ran it will be a non-trivial subgroup of $G$

Comment: You wrote "What happens if g has finite order" . Would you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @rama_ran you need to show that $G$ has a subgroup. If $g$ has finite order, can you see a way of showing that